# nodejs(koa):Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, koa

I have a program which want to  map `/a/b/c.js` url => `/a:b:c.js` file;

`koa version:2.3.0
koa static version: 4.0.1`

minimal reproduction

```
const KOA = require('koa');
const koaStatic = require('koa-static');

staticApp = new KOA()
staticApp.use((ctx, next) => {
  let path = ctx.path.split('/');
  path = path.filter(segment => segment)
  ctx.path = `/${path.join(':')}`;
  next()
})
staticApp.use(koaStatic(__dirname))
staticApp.listen(8888);
```

Assume current directory have a file `a:b:c.js`, 
when I access to `locahost:8888\a\b\c.js` in browser, 
program always get error 
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

thanks for you help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
const KOA = require('koa');
const koaStatic = require('koa-static');

staticApp = new KOA()
staticApp.use((ctx, next) => {
  let path = ctx.path.split('/');
  path = path.filter(segment => segment)
  ctx.path = `/${path.join(':')}`;
  return next();
});
staticApp.use(koaStatic(__dirname));
staticApp.listen(8888);
```

It seems that if you want to use a common function as middleware, you have to return the next function.

Comment: Do you know the reason  why common function as middlerware have to return the next function? thk

Comment: @Qiu I think it's because you have to return a promise from your middleware to work with other middlewares. The next return a promise, as you return it, you return a promise. See this issue for more discussions https://github.com/koajs/koa/issues/997

Answer (score 0):

I found that to resolve this problem I had to disable some middleware on some routes. In my case it was passport.js middleware that was setting cookies, which I wanted NOT to happen on requests through the /proxy path. This is my solution:

```js
const blacklistRoute = (fn, p) => async (ctx, next) => {
  if (ctx.request.path.startsWith(p)) {
    return next()
  } else {
    return fn(ctx, next)
  }
}

const app = ...

app
  .use(
    blacklistRoute(
      koaSession(passportCookieConfig, app),
      '/proxy'
    )
  )
```